# Why am I getting duplicate results from this script?

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

Some rows are being printed out multiple times, the variable $foo shows that its the foreach($students as $student) loop but I just can't figure out why it's happening.

This is a custom report in Moodle

Here's my code

```
require_once('../../config.php');
require_once($CFG->libdir . '/adminlib.php');

admin_externalpage_setup('reportlink_critic', '', null, '',  array('pagelayout'=>'report'));

echo $OUTPUT->header();
echo $OUTPUT->heading(get_string('pluginname', 'report_link_critic'));

$table = new html_table();

$table->head = array('Student', 'Links Posted', 'Votes Received', 'Cumalative Score', 'Rating', 'Foo');
$table->headspan = array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

$query_students = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM mdl_user WHERE confirmed = '1' AND deleted = '0'";

$students = $DB->get_recordset_sql($query_students);

$foo = 1;

foreach( $students as $student ) {

    $query_links = "SELECT count(id), user_id AS links_posted FROM mdl_link_critic_links WHERE user_id = '" . $student->id . "'";
    $links = $DB->get_recordset_sql($query_links);

    foreach($links as $link) {
        $links_posted = $link->links_posted;
    }

    $query_votes = "SELECT count(v.id) AS votes FROM mdl_link_critic_votes v JOIN mdl_link_critic_links l ON l.id = v.link_id WHERE l.user_id = '" . $student->id . "' ";
    $votes = $DB->get_recordset_sql($query_votes);

    foreach($votes as $vote) {
        $total_votes = $vote->votes;
    }

    $query_scores = "SELECT sum(v.vote_score) as score FROM mdl_link_critic_votes v WHERE user_id = '" . $student->id . "' ";
    $scores = $DB->get_recordset_sql($query_scores);

    foreach($scores as $score) {
        $cumalative_score = $score->score;
    }

    $foo = $foo + 1;

    if($links_posted > 0) {
        $rating = round(($total_votes * $cumalative_score) / $links_posted, 2);
        $cells = array( $student->firstname . ' ' . $student->lastname, $links_posted, $total_votes, $cumalative_score, $rating, $foo );
    }

    if(!empty($cells)) {    
        $table->data[] = new html_table_row($cells);
    }


}

echo html_writer::table($table);

$students->close();
$links->close();
$votes->close();
$scores->close();

echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

The report prints out each row as student name, votes received, cumalative score, Rating and my count of $foo, but some students are printed out several times ? Very confused

Comment: Try using $DB->get_records_sql() and then calling var_dump on the result, that should give you a bit more info on the records that you are looping through. Even better, use $DB->get_records('user', ['confirmed' => 1, 'deleted' => 0], '', 'id, firstname, lastname') - that is a better use of the Moodle DB API.

Comment: Seems you forgot the + inside the different foreach (ie $total_votes += $vote->votes). A typo ?

Comment: Ok I did a var_dump, using the $DB->get_records and I get the correct result, each student once in the the var_dump, but still duplicated records output to the table..

Comment: You do not reset the variable `$cells` when `$links_posted = 0`. So if a student has `$links_posted = 0`, it will print the last student again.

Comment: You are right @Solarflare - I wasn't initializing cells - so I added $cells = array() before everything else in the foreach($students as $student) loop and it fixed it. Well spotted.